# Was the Latin verb "stimulare" ("to stimulate", from the noun "stimulus" meaning "sting") attested in the meaning "to sting (of an insect)"?

Tags: vocabulary

The Latin verb "stimulare" (to urge, to stimulate) comes from the noun "stimulus" (sting of a bee or a similar animal). Was it ever attested in the meaning "to sting (of a bee)"?

By the way, how would you say "*It stings me like a bee.*" in Latin?

Comment: Are you sure *stimulus* ever meant 'beesting' or similar? It's certainly not its primary meaning.

Comment: @Cairnarvon https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stimulus#Latin

Comment: It says 'sting' but it means that in a broad sense, not idiomatically an insect's sting; click through to Lewis and Short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that "it stings me like a bee" might be rendered as *aculeo icit me*, literally, "it smites me with a stinger".

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [Etymonline Stimulus](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=stimulus)

its use, especially in medicine, is more attached to the common pricking instruments used to get the cattle or horses into motion.